Equational basis for Cartesian product, union, intersection, and the empty set
Let $M$ be a model of ZFC set theory, and consider the algebraic structure $(M;\times,\cup,\cap,\emptyset)$, where $\times$ represents Cartesian product based on the Kuratowski ordered pair, and the other symbols are well-known. Is there a finite basis for the identities of that structure? I conjecture that, in addition to a finite basis for union, intersection, and the empty set, all we need are these identities: $x \times \emptyset = \emptyset \times x = \emptyset$, $x \times (y \cup z) = (x \times y) \cup (x \times z)$, $(x \cup y) \times z = (x \times z) \cup (y \times z)$, $x \times (y \cap z) = (x \times y) \cap (x \times z)$, and $(x \cap y) \times z = (x \times z) \cap (y \times z)$. Is this all that is sufficent, or do we need a bit more?
